# Shifting UIview Controls upword whne load iad ads

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have developing one in that implementing inAppPurchase after user buy app from inAppPurchase all ads renove all that are done but now my problem is that after removing iad ads my tableview will appear at whole screen and my another uiviewcontroller Automatically lad at full screen

Comment: try setting content size of UIScrollview...

Comment: Have you tried to resize the UITableView and removing the ad view from superview?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define all your view pragmatically. and set each an every controller size before ads. and also set the size of your view controller after the ads reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

As u got the methods of product purchase in your code accordingly resize the uiview size.